# React/Redux actions not firing onClick, but exists in component props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, jsx

I have gone through each line of code. Checked the mapDispatchToProps, checked the reducer, varied the order in which every case in the reducer-switch is fired, tried rendering each component in solo mode, as well as without conditional render. I've created a sayHello action that only console logs sayHello. The thing is: SOME actions are working. especially those created before a certain occation (can't se when).

My simple action:

```
export function sayHello(){

return {
    type: 'SAY_HELLO'
}
```

The case in the reducer taking care of the action:

```
case 'SAY_HELLO':
        console.log('HELLO WORLD')
        newState = {...newState}

        return newState;
```

A button that should fire the action (i do console.log on the component containing this button and it does in fact include the sayHello function as well as every other function mapped through dispatch):

```
<button onClick={this.props.sayHello}>sayhello</button>
```

The mapDispatchToProps:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
return {
        changeView: (event) => {
            dispatch(changeView(event))
        },

        updateCarChoice: (event) => {
            dispatch(updateCarChoice(event))
        },

        bookCar: (event) => {
            dispatch(bookCar(event))
        },

        addCar: (event) => {
            dispatch: ( addCar(event))
        },

        removeCar: (event) => {
            dispatch: ( removeCar(event))
        },

        handleSignIn: (event) => {
            dispatch: (handleSignIn (event))
        },

        updateAuthObject: (event) => {
            dispatch: (updateAuthObject (event))
        },

        handleCreateAccount: (event) => {
            dispatch: (handleCreateAccount (event))
        },

        changeAuthType: (event) => {
            dispatch: (changeAuthType (event))
        },

        sayHello: () => {
            dispatch: (sayHello ())
        }


    }
```

};

Store:

```
import {createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import {createLogger} from 'redux-logger';

import mainReducer from '../reducers/mainReducer';
import carsReducer from '../reducers/carsReducer';
import logInReducer from '../reducers/logInReducer';


export default createStore(
    combineReducers({
        mainReducer,
        carsReducer,
        logInReducer
    }),
    applyMiddleware(createLogger())
);
```

index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './components/App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import './index.css';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import store from './store/store';

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root'));

registerServiceWorker();
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you show me your store and your root reducer?

Comment: Can you please post your `mapDispatchToProps` or `sayHello` method, that will be more helpful in finding the cause.

Comment: @vs1682 code added. I get the lint warning saying that "dispatch is defined but never used". But the actions looks just like the initial ones like changeView (which is working properly).

Comment: @AlessanderFrança added!

Comment: `sayHello: () => { dispatch: (sayHello ()) }` i guess the problem is here. Change it to `dispatch(sayHello())`

Answer (score 0):

Your are not returning your dispatch:

```
changeView: (event) => {
            dispatch(changeView(event))
        },
```

Should be

```
changeView: (event) => dispatch(changeView(event))
```